# 2D index of numpy array using array indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

If I have a 2D array of indices:

```
i = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1]])
```

And a 2D array I want to index:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

How can I index the array to get a 1D array like the following?

```
np.array([1, 4])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
a[i.T[0], i.T[1]]
```

In case you have more dimensions, you can use:

```
a[tuple(i.T)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple indexing:

```
In [11]: a[i[:, 0], i[:, 1]]
Out[11]: array([1, 4])
```

The first column of `i` is number of rows and the second one denotes the column number.